# What is the rate at which the Nearby API for android Broadcasts the adverstiments?

Tags: android, google-nearby

What is the speed at which the broadcasts happens when we advertise using Nearby API in Android? Also, is there any way the speed can be controlled?

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing you are talking about the Nearby Connections API. In my observations, (pure empirical evidence) in most cases you will be able to discover devices in less than 5 seconds, some older devices can take longer. Anyway, there is no way to directly control these events in the API.